# Why is the color of fire is yellow or blue sometimes?

Tags: visible-light, spectroscopy, combustion

If you light up any thing it burns in yellow and as well when you light up a gas stove it burns in blue color. What brings this color change?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bunsen Burners and the Sun](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64512/)

Comment: Related (though not a duplicate): [Possible colors of fire?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44664/)